# Horizontal Scroll bar not available in pdf generated using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I have created pdf with images and other pdfs in c# using **iTextSharp** library, and its working fine except there is no horizontal bar. It causing the content to be cropped. Is there any way to make the horizontal scroll bar visible/available?

Following is the function that i am using for the same:

```
string pdfpath = Server.MapPath("~/uploads");

string imagepath = Server.MapPath("~/uploads");

Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);

try

{

    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(pdfpath + "/Images.pdf", FileMode.Create));
    doc.Open();

    doc.Add(new Paragraph("file 1 "));               
    Image gif = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(model.file1.InputStream);
    doc.Add(gif);

    doc.Add(new Paragraph("file 2 "));
    Image file2 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(model.file2.InputStream);
    doc.Add(file2);

    doc.Add(new Paragraph("file 3 "));
    Image file3 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(model.file3.InputStream);
    doc.Add(file3);


    doc.Add(new Paragraph("file 4 "));                

    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(model.file4.InputStream);

    for (int i = 1; i <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; i++)
    {
        PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, i);                        
        doc.Add(file4);                        
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
finally
{
    doc.Close();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a horizontal scroll bar not appearing - obviously a pdf file is sized to a specific page size (A4, A2 etc) so if an image doesn't fit the given width available then it will be cropped - what else would you expect to if you were to print your document ? Try changing the page size (which your code sample doesn't specify).

Comment: Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER); where else i have to specify the pagesize?

Comment: ok PageSize.LETTER is 11 inches height by 8.5 inches wide so if that's too small for the images you're displaying either reduce the size of the images or use a larger page size